# Angular 2, bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have an modal

```
<div bsModal #largeModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Create Goal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <p>Modal body text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I am using http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#modal-directive

but I cant figure out how to react on the directive outputs such as onHide/onShow etc.

I would like to do some processing when the modal is hidden for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add listen to output events. for example **'onHidden'**

```
<div bsModal #largeModal="bs-modal" (onHidden)="onHidden()" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Create Goal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <p>Modal body text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when ever your model hidden it will execute onHidden Function.

In the file Component add onHidden() function.

```
public onHidden() {
    // do our stuff 
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Are the 'keywords' then: onHidden, onHide, onShow, onShown, onLoaded?